# wxPython New, Save, and SaveAs Methods

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm writing a UI for a python app with wxPython.  I've handled a few of the OnX functions but I need help with OnNew and OnSave/SaveAs

Here is my Save and SaveAs code:

```
def OnSave(self, event):
    self.dirname = ""
    saveFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save Operation File", self.dirname, "",
        "Operation Files (*.fwr)|*.fwr|All Files (*.*)|*.*", wx.SAVE|wx.OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
    if saveFileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        contents = self.control.GetValue()
        self.filename = saveFileDialog.GetFilename()
        self.dirname = saveFileDialog.GetDirectory()
        filehandle = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w')
        filehandle.write(contents)
        filehandle.close()
    else:
        sys.exit(1)
    saveFileDialog.Destroy()

def OnSaveAs(self, event):
    self.dirname = "";

    saveAsFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save Operation File As", self.dirname, "",
        "Operation Files (*.fwr)|*.fwr|All Files (*.*)|*.*", 
        wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)

    if saveAsFileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        contents = self.control.GetValue()
        self.filename = saveFileDialog.GetFilename()
        self.dirname = saveFileDialog.GetDirectory()
        filehandle = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w')
        filehandle.write(contents)
        filehandle.close()
    else:
        sys.exit(1)
    saveFileDialog.Destroy()

    # save current contents in the file
    # use wxPython output streams
    #output_stream = wx.FileOutputStream(saveFileDialog.GetPath())

    #if not output_stream.IsOk():    
    #    wx.LogError("Cannot save contents of Operations File '%s'" % saveFileDialog.GetPath())
    #    return
```

the commented part at the bottom is another way I found to do it, is using the input and output streams more correct than the way it currently is?  Also heres my other question, I got OnNew Working, here is the code:

```
def OnNew(self,  event):
    homedir = os.environ['HOME']
    if not os.path.exists(homedir):
        if getpass.getuser():
            homedir = "C:/Users/" + getpass.getuser() + "/"
        else:
            homedir = "C:/"
    newFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "New Operation File", homedir, "",
        "Operation Files (*.fwr)|*.fwr|All Files|(*.*)|*.*", wx.FD_CREATE|wx.OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
```

Everything is great but the OnOpen Method opens an open file dialog, I want a create file dialog (would this be the same as save? Can someone give me an example OnOpen method, and give me some insight into my OnSave and OnSaveAs methods?  As you can see there are three aproaches, one in OnSaveAs, one in OnSave, and one commented out at the bottom of OnSaveAs().  As well as many more  I didn't write down here.  My main question though is how to get the filedialog for new to be a save dialog where you create a file, rather than an open dialog.

Thanks a ton.

SUMMARY:

1) How do you bring up a FileDialog that allows creation of blank files.  I assum it will be similar to save, but hwatever ID flags I pass it always gives me an  Open button

2) And as for save methods, is it better to do what I showed in the code, or use streams like the commented out section in SaveAs?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Save dialog, you need to pass the `wx.SAVE` style flag to your `FileDialog` object: `style=wx.SAVE`. You can read more about the save flag [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/26/the-dialogs-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524525/implement-save-as-in-save-dialog-wxpython).

Here's some example code that worked for me on Xubuntu 14.04 with wxPython 2.8.12.1 and Python 2.7:

```
import os
import wx

wildcard = "Python source (*.py)|*.py|" \
            "All files (*.*)|*.*"

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "File and Folder Dialogs Tutorial")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.currentDirectory = os.getcwd()

        saveFileDlgBtn = wx.Button(panel, label="Show SAVE FileDialog")
        saveFileDlgBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSaveFile)

        # put the buttons in a sizer
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(saveFileDlgBtn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onSaveFile(self, event):
        """
        Create and show the Save FileDialog
        """
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(
            self, message="Save file as ...", 
            defaultDir=self.currentDirectory, 
            defaultFile="", wildcard=wildcard, style=wx.FD_SAVE
            )
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()
            print "You chose the following filename: %s" % path
        dlg.Destroy()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I don't see anything wrong with your saving approach. In most cases, it's better to use Python's low level operators instead of using wxPython's. I would use Python's `with` operator though as that follows the newer idiom better:

```
with open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w') as filehandle:
    filehandle.write(contents)
```

Comment: I tried passing that to the FileDialog, but it still gives me the open button

Comment: I updated the example with a simple example that worked on my end.

Comment: Just an update: You should use `wx.FD_SAVE` instead of `wx.SAVE` (at least in 4.0.0b2).

Comment: Yeah, this wasn't enforced until wxPython 4.